# Adding KML Layer to Google Map via external js file

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

Found this plugin:

[jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/wehelie/jQuery-geocomplete)

but I'm trying to add a custom marker as well as a KML Layer but I don't know how to add it to the external js file.

The code I want to add is the following but I'm not sure how to implement it.

```
  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://pa-nature.supermarchepa.com/assets/pa-nature.kmz'
});
ctaLayer.setMap(map);

var natureMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: nature,
    map: map,
    icon: 'http://pa-nature.supermarchepa.com/assets/pa-solo-map.svg',
    title: 'PA Nature'
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with the geocomplete library to get started: http://jsfiddle.net/4qgugd7a/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mcf2280/nug70t0t/1/

The marker is in Australia.

added (line 96) `this.foo();`

```
$.extend(GeoComplete.prototype, {
init: function(){
  this.initMap();
    this.foo();
  this.initMarker();
  this.initGeocoder();
  this.initDetails();
  this.initLocation();
},
```

added (line 132)

```
foo :function(){
    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://pa-nature.supermarchepa.com/assets/pa-nature.kmz'
    });
    ctaLayer.setMap(this.map);
    var nature = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
    var natureMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: nature,
        map: this.map,
        icon: 'http://pa-nature.supermarchepa.com/assets/pa-solo-map.svg',
        title: 'PA Nature'
    });        
},
```